# How to save a bitmap in the gallery?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, gallery

So I have a bitmap and after I edit it I want that the User can save it and see it in the gallery. I was searching in google and a found many Ideas but all I tried didn't work. This is my code:

```
        ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id. imageButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
            // immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity7.this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

So whats wrong or do you have any other solutions how I can save my bitmap in the gallery?

Comment: When you examine LogCat, do you see a stack trace coming from your app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > App and find Storage permission is allowed for your app or not. If not, allow it and try again.